# Hendo: Does it need a specific floor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the Hendo board need a specific floor underneath it? https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/142464853/hendo-hoverboards-worlds-first-real-hoverboard

Comment: Why would you ask that here rather than there?

Comment: Because obviously we're world class experts on absolutely everything, including things that other people are developing and haven't released yet. We know everything - I thought you knew that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the page you linked to:

> Currently, this surface substrate needs to be a non-ferromagnetic conductor. Right now we use commonly available metals in simple sheets, but we are working on new compounds and new configurations to maximize our technology and minimize costs.

Comment: Well... thats a preety useless hoverboard. Just saying...

Comment: @Golaž I expect battery life will be rather disappointing for something that will levitate 100kg (or even my 100lb senior firmware engineer)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I cant imagine how such a lousy project could get so much attention. While there are probably other more "innovative" projects out there.

Comment: @Golaž People want to believe that something they see in movies is really possible, and they lack the engineering judg(e)ment to see that it's not gonna happen in any meaningful way anytime soon. Sad, because it poisons the well for better projects.

Comment: I looked all over their page and couldn’t find it! Good job :D

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Any idea how it works?  I was thinking if you had enough velocity and permanent magnets you could get some mag lev.  Soooo... if I had some spinning magnets???

Comment: Here's an answer and patent link.  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142732/how-does-hendo-hoverboards-achieve-the-self-propelling-motion-what-is-the-mfa